# Android Compose - Error "Snapshot is not open" after app build

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have LazyColumn and I want to scroll it to exact position, after user stops scroll.
I use next code to scroll:

```
composableScope.launch {
    listState.animateScrollToItem(
        index = indexToScroll,
        scrollOffset = offsetToScroll
    )
}
```

All works as expected, except one thing. After **the first launch from Android studio**, I always get crash *java.lang.IllegalStateException: Snapshot is not open*. If I opened the application without building or run build the second time (without code changes) all work well.
I have created a gist with an example of my code

```
@Composable
fun MyComponent() {
    val composableScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState
    ) {
        .....
    }

    val isScrollInProgress by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            listState.isScrollInProgress
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(isScrollInProgress) {
        if(!isScrollInProgress){
            val visiblePlaceHeight = listState.layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset + listState.layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset
            val itemHeight = listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.firstOrNull()?.size
            itemHeight?.let {
                val centerPosition = (visiblePlaceHeight - itemHeight) / 2
                val offsetToScroll = itemHeight - centerPosition
                val indexToScroll = when (listState.firstVisibleItemIndex) {
                    listState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount - 2 -> listState.firstVisibleItemIndex - 1
                    else -> listState.firstVisibleItemIndex
                }
                if (listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset != offsetToScroll && offsetToScroll > 0) {
                    composableScope.launch {
                        // listState.animateScrollToItem leads to java.lang.IllegalStateException: Snapshot is not open
                        listState.animateScrollToItem(
                            index = indexToScroll,
                            scrollOffset = offsetToScroll
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove code in *composableScope.launch {...}* the problem disappeared.

Comment: please ad more context, where is this code called?

Comment: I added a full example of my composable method

Answer (score 0):

`LaunchedEffect` block is already called on a coroutine scope, so there's no need to wrap `animateScrollToItem` with an other coroutine.

Basic example: the list will scroll to item `40` after a second delay from the time the view appears.

```kotlin
val listState = rememberLazyListState()

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    delay(1000)
    listState.animateScrollToItem(40)
}

LazyColumn(
    state = listState
) {
    items(100) {
        Text(text = it.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried call animateScrollToItem without composableScope.launch, but the list doesn't scroll.
Do you know a good example of code for LaunchedEffect and scroll?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/951896a1538094082bfe5f2e602f24c4 this works totally fine

Comment: Hi @Arseniy did this answer solved your question? If so, please accept it using the checkmark under the votes counter.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem. But your code helped me understand some other details. I am going to post the full code of my example with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it also happended in my compose application
i tried making minifyEnabled false, and it didn't c rash again
so you can set minify in **build.gradle**,

```
minifyEnabled false
```

or keep compose's classes in **proguard-rules.pro**

```
-keep public class androidx.compose.*.**{*;}
```

Comment: Setting minifyEnabled to false is not a solution for production apps. It will make our code vulnerable to reverse engineering.